# Cant log in to BeagleBone Black's SSH through my Mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am new to the BeagleBone Black and I have so far been unable to connect the BeagleBone with my Mac and successfully log in to SSH.

I have downloaded and installed both HoRNDIS and FTDI_ser but this has not helped.

I have also allowed remote log in's through my Macs network preferences.

The connection I am attempting to make is with an Ethernet connector and uses an Ethernet to USB adapter.

When I try **ssh root@192.168.7.2** through my terminal the connection is just timing out.

Can anyone suggest something else I could try or what might be preventing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how a Ethernet to USB adapter works but using the plain USB adapter that comes with the BeagleBone Black, after installing the above mentioned drivers, you need to restart the Mac and then try opening `http://192.168.7.2` or ssh root@192.168.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post that I am responding to but for others who may be having same problem.....First off, if you installed all drivers and when you plug in USB to your Mac and the BBB does not show up as a removable drive then try the steps below. If it does, then type `ls /dev/tty.*` in your terminal and look for an output on the terminal tty.USB0. Then serial connect to that tty. **If all else fails try this failproof method for serial connecting to BBB**

1. Get USB to UART debug connector [find it on Amazon here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SL0U3RG)
2. Install the CP2102 drivers for Mac
3. Type `ls /dev/tty.*` on terminal (of course have it connected to Mac
4. Your terminal should output a device named `tty.SLAB_USBtoUART`
5. Serial connect to that tty name with a baud rate of 115200
6. Power your BBB (you can use the USB connector that comes with BBB to power it on, so you should have one USB connected for powering the BBB and the other is the debug connector connected to your mac for a serial connect.
7. Bam! You should see Uboot output and a prompt to login